# Perl: duplicate keys not overwriting in hash

Tags: arrays, perl, hash, duplicates, key

I have a problem that I can't seem to find an answer for.

I have a CSV file that contains performance records for different individuals. There is only suppose to be one record per individual, however, there are some individuals that have several records with different information.  I would like to compare this first file to another that also has a list of individuals, though I would only like to compare whether the individual in file 1 also has a record in file two (file 2 does not have duplicates). The individuals' IDs are unique.

Example for file 1:

```
ID number      A       B     C            D
4011NM16001    apple   24    sunday       2016-01-01
4011NM16001    apple   16    wednesday    2016-01-01
4012NM15687    pear    16    sunday       2015-04-19
4012NM15002    banana  8     monday       2015-09-09
4012NM14301    peach   10    wednesday    2014-03-18
4012NM14301    peach   18    wednesday    2014-03-18
```

I have opened the first file and tried to put the data into a hash (or rather a combination of a hash and array if I understand the concepts correctly) so as to remove the duplicates, using the ID as the unique key. However, instead of overwriting entries with the same ID, it still seems to add it, so I still end up with the duplicate records.

I want to see this:

```
ID number
4011NM16001
4011NM15687
4012NM15002
4012NM14301
```

But instead I still see this:

```
ID number      
4011NM16001    
4011NM16001    
4012NM15687    
4012NM15002    
4012NM14301    
4012NM14301
```

Have I typed something wrong in my code or am I not using the hash correctly? I'm still new to Perl so I use parts of previous programs and try to learn as I go..

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use DBI;

use strict;
use warnings;

my $file1  = 'location1.csv';   #file1 containing records with duplicates
my $exists = 'location3.csv';  #output file with unique IDs that will be compared to file2

open (EXISTS, ">$exists") or die "Cannot open $exists";
    print EXISTS "ID number\n";

open (FILE1, "$file1") or die "Cannot open $file1";

while (<FILE1>){

    my %file1;

    my $line = $_;
    $line =~ s/\s*$//g;

    my ($ID, $a, $b, $c, $d) = split('\,', $line);
    next if !$ID or substr($ID,0,2) eq 'ID';

    $file1{$ID}[0]=$ID;  #unique ID number
    $file1{$ID}[1]=$a;   #record a
    $file1{$ID}[2]-$b;   #record b
    $file1{$ID}[3]=$c;   #record c
    $file1{$ID}[4]=$d;   #record d

    print EXISTS "$file1{$ID}[0]\n";
}

exit;
```

Comment: I imagine that you know you don't need `use DBI` in there? The module is never used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to [choroba's diagnosis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38350747/622310) you need to declare the hash *outside* the `while` loop, otherwise each iteration of the loop is dealing with a new empty hash

Here's a version of your code that uses best-practice Perl and produces the result that you wanted. Note that I've had to alter the format of your input file `location1.csv` as the values you show don't contain any commas

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $file1  = 'location1.csv';    # file1 containing records with duplicates
my $exists = 'location3.csv';    # output file with unique IDs that will be compared to file2

open my $exists_fh, '>', $exists or die qq{Unable to open "$exists" for output: $!};
print $exists_fh "ID number\n";

open my $file1_fh, '<', $file1 or die qq{Unable to open "$file1" for input: $!};
<$file1_fh>; # skip header line

my %file1;

while ( <$file1_fh> ) {

    next unless /\S/; # Skip blank lines

    s/\s+\z//;

    my @fields = split /,/;
    my $id = $fields[0];

    next if $file1{$id}; # Skip this record if the ID is already known

    $file1{$id} = \@fields;

    print $exists_fh "$id\n"
}
```

#### output

```
ID number
4011NM16001
4012NM15687
4012NM15002
4012NM14301
```

Comment: thaks for your answer!! I have now tried declaring the hash and print outside the while loop (ie after the last } bracket), but it then gives the "Global symbol .. requires explicit package name" error for $file1 and $ID variables, which as I understand means the variable hasn't been declared. I' try your code next - does it still add all the data into a hash/array (ie all the data from all columns), or will it only extract the unique values in the ID column?

Comment: @DKru:  You can either print the contents of the hash after the `while` loop or just use it to determine whether the ID has been seen before, and print each new ID *inside* the loop, which is what my code does

Comment: `Global symbol .. requires explicit package name` does indeed mean that a variable hasn't been declared (There are moves to change that message to something more useful!) and that is because you have moved your `print` statement outside the loop where `$ID` doesn't exist. But unless you've changed something else, `$file1` should exists everywhere in the program so I'm not sure what's going on. Even if you mean `%file1`, you say you have moved its declaration outside the loop so that should be fine too. It's impossible to debug your code any further without seeing what you have written

Answer (score 4):

You are printing the line for each input line, not for non-existent lines only.
Move the `print` before the assignment paragraph and change it to

```
print EXISTS "$ID\n" unless exists $file1{$ID};
```

Comment: Congratulations on going past 100k :)

Comment: @simbabque: Thanks. Still waiting for the "box of cool stuff" :-)

Comment: Good luck with customs on that. They declared my 10m question win box with way too low prices, like 1$ for the t-shirt, but it went through. I think it also had 10x 0.10$ for stickers.

Comment: Please bring your SO t-shirt to YAPC if you got it by then.

Comment: @choroba: Is that still a thing?

Comment: @Borodin: Well, why are we here? :-)